# Python: Search a string for a number, decrement that number and replace in the string

Tags: python

If I have a string such as:

```
string = 'Output1[10].mystruct.MyArray[4].mybool'
```

what I want to do is search the string for the number in the array, decrement by 1 and then replace the found number with my decremented number.

What I have tried:

```
import string
import re

string = 'Output1[10].mystruct.MyArray[4].mybool'
pattern = r'\[(\d+)\]'
num = re.findall(pattern, string)
```

So, I can get a list of the numbers, convert to integers but I don't know how to use re.sub to search the string to replace, it should be considered that there might be multiple arrays. If anyone is expert enough to do that, help much appreciated.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I don't undestand a thing... If there is more than 1 array, do you want to decrease the number in all arrays? or just in 1 of them?

If you want to decrease in all arrays, you can do this:

```
import re

string = 'Output1[10].mystruct.MyArray[4].mybool'
pattern = r'\[(\d+)\]'
num = re.findall(pattern, string)
num = [int(elem) for elem in num]
num.sort()

for elem in num:
     aux = elem - 1
     string = string.replace(str(elem), str(aux))
```

If you want to decrease just the first array, you can do this

```
import string
import re

string = 'Output1[10].mystruct.MyArray[4].mybool'
pattern = r'\[(\d+)\]'
num = re.findall(pattern, string)
new_num = int(num[0]) - 1
string = string.replace(num[0], str(new_num), 1)
```

Comment: You could end up decreasing the same value multiple times with this solution. E.g.: The string contains a 10 and a 9. The 10 is decreased first to 9 and then in the next step both 9s are decreased to 8. Or am I missing something?

Comment: I tested your first solution with the string ```'Output1[10].mystruct.MyArray[9].mybool'``` and it results in ```'Output1[8].mystruct.MyArray[8].mybool'``` as I suspected. We somehow have to make sure that the same numbers aren't touched twice.

Comment: @lema you're totally right. I just edited my answer

Comment: Thanks, it is almost there. When the index is 1, all numbers in the string will be changed - so Output1[1] will become Output0[0] - I was under the impression that re.sub would allow some fancy calculation when the match is made to do the decrement and then make the replacement.
This seems much more tricky than I first thought.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to @João Castilho for his answer, based on this I changed it slightly to work exactly how I want:

```
import string
import re

string = 'Output1[2].mystruct.MyArray[2].mybool'
pattern = r'\[(\d+)\]'
num = re.findall(pattern, string)
num = [int(elem) for elem in set(num)]
num.sort()

for elem in num:
     aux = elem - 1
     string = string.replace('[%d]'% elem, '[%d]'% aux)

print(string)
```

This will now replace any number between brackets with the decremented value in all of the conditions that the numbers may occur.

Cheers

ice.